# View locally saved content from Mozilla Firefox

Tags: firefox, caching, media, history

When browsing with Mozilla Firefox and loading a webpage with an audio file, that audio file should be saved in a media cache locally, right?

Is there a method or addon/tool for selecting, from Mozilla's display of the webpage, that audio file in the media cache and saving it?

Answer (score 0):

CacheViewer Continued does what I wanted, without a context menu option.
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cacheviewer-continued/